# Unknown error (0x5011) with ActiveDirectory PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, active-directory

I am trying to get the UserGroups that the user belongs to from MVC application using PrinicipalContect object.

Here is the Code Reference from: http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/

For my userID (DOMAIN A), I am able to retrieve all the Groups that i belong to.
Now I tried to get the Groups of UserB who is under DOMAIN A. This also worked fine.

Now i am trying to get the Groups of UserC who is under a different Domain DOMAIN B.

It is throwing an error as below.
Anyone has any idea about this.

```
    **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:**
    Unknown error (0x5011).

    **ERROR CODE:** 
    20497    

    **Message:**
    Unknown error (0x5011).

    **StackTrace:** 
    at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.GetNextSearchResult()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNextMemberSearcher()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNext()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNConstraintLinkedAttrSet.MoveNext()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Does your UserC contain special characters in its DistinguishedName (e.g. / )?

Comment: No Special characters. Looks like microsoft provided hotfix for Windows 7 based cients/ Windows server 2008 standard servers talking to Active Directory gateways. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969429

Answer (score 6):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969166